# Is there any way make column for each category under each group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

There are two column both are categorical. I want to groupby by first columns lets `age_group` and my other column `Engagement_category` should make new column by each element.

I did the groupby on first column `age_group`.

```
| age_group    | Engagement_category |
|--------------|---------------------|
| 21-26        | Not Engaged         |
| 27-32        | Disengaged          |
| 33-38        | Engaged             |
| 39-44        | Disengaged          |
| 45-50        | Not Engaged         |
| 50 and Above | Engaged             |
```

```
group = df.groupby('age_group')
```

The below one is required output:

```
| age_group | Engaged | Nearly Engaged | Not Engaged | Disengaged |
|-----------|---------|----------------|-------------|------------|
| 21-26     | 3       | 4              | 1           | 1          |
| 27-32     | 4       | 0              | 4           | 0          |
| 33-38     | 2       | 0              | 1           | 1          |
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where are these values coming from? Seems you just have random numbers in the output.  It seems like you just want `pd.crosstab(df['Age'], df['Engagement_category'])` though.

Answer (score 0):

You want to group by the first two columns then use the "COUNT" function to aggregate across the dataframe. Try this:

```
df.groupby(['Age', 'Engagement_category']).agg(['count'])
```

Comment: df.groupby(['Age','Engagement_category'])['Engagement_category'].count()